# How to stop a set of HTML figures from shifting when hovering over them

Tags: css, html

I'm working on something in my free time, a little selection tool for a game I play, Dota2.

I've poured the entire HTML output of the current situation in to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8T6L/

This has a list of checkboxes and a list of items. These are figures, all set to `display: table`. The idea is that when I click one or more checkboxes, only items possessing the selected attributes will remain shown. That functionality isn't complete yet, so if you click a checkbox, everything will disappear. Simply uncheck everything to make it appear again.

Each item is a `<figure>` with and `<img>` and `<figcaption>`. Locally I'm generating the entire set with some PHP, I just copied the HTML/CSS/JavaScript so I could make the fiddle.

I was trying to add a border when you hover over an item, but this is shifting the items in some cases.

The relevant CSS code can be found on the fiddle at line 438:

```
figure {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 120px;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 15px auto; /* not needed unless you want centered */
    margin-top: 5px;
}

figure:hover {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;/*Should be good with all browsers*/

    border-style: inset;
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

I've tried playing with margins and padding(some of that left in the code), even with border-collapse, but nothing seems to work. What I'm trying to achieve here is that when I hover over the figure, an inset appears to let the user know which item is highlighted without anything moving even a pixel. Just the inset appearing.

I realize I could do this with `background-color` instead, if my intent is simply to let the user know which item is being hovered over, but then I wouldn't know the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because it's adding pixels around the image when you hover. You should set your initial class with a `border: 1px solid transparent;` so that when you hover you aren't adding pixels but just changing the border color.

```
    figure {
        text-align: center;
        display: table;
        width: 120px;
        height: 90px;
        padding: 15px auto; /* not needed unless you want centered */
        margin-top: 5px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    figure:hover {
        cursor: hand;
        cursor: pointer;/*Should be good with all browsers*/
        border-color: #000;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer can be so simple sometimes :(

Answer (score 1):

Mathew is spot on with the reason (+1) another approach is to use `outline` instead of border:

```
figure:hover {
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;/*Should be good with all browsers*/   
  outline-style: inset;
  outline-color: #000;
  outline-width: 1px;
}
```

This should have the added benefit of working on browsers that don't support transparent for borders (i.e. IE6) if you are bothering to support such dodery old things. The down side is that the outline will caculate outside of the element, so if you run these elements up against the side of the page you may loose part of your border.

Comment: Indeed, though I'll be using the classList element in JavaScript, which is only supported in IE10. Still, thanks.